# CLOSを利用した場合に、defmethodで定義したメソッドが組み込み関数と被るときの対処法

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

CommonLispの勉強のため、CLOS(Common Lisp Object System)を利用してスタック構造を実装しているところです。

スタック構造なので、メソッド名に`pop`と`push`というのを定義したいのですが、CLOSの仕様上、そのまま定義しようとすると、既にCommon Lispの組み込み関数として定義されている`pop`と`push`と被ってしまいます。このとき、メソッド名をリネームして衝突を回避することは可能だと思いますが、それよりは`pop`・`push`のメソッド名のまま利用したいと考えています。このとき、Common Lispではどのように解決するのが望ましいと言えるのでしょうか?

汚いですが、具体的なコードも掲載しておきます:

```
  (defclass stack () ((state :accessor state :initform '())))
  (defmethod push ((stack-obj stack) elem)
    (let ((new-stack
           (if (state stack-obj) (cons elem (state stack-obj)) (list elem))))
      (setf (state stack-obj) new-stack)))
  (defmethod pop ((stack-obj stack))
    (let ((pop-stack (car (state stack-obj))))
      (progn (setf (state stack-obj) (cdr (state stack-obj)))
             pop-stack)))
```

また、`sbcl`処理系を利用した場合のエラーメッセージは以下のようになります:

```
  Unhandled SYMBOL-PACKAGE-LOCKED-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD
                                                    "main thread" RUNNING
                                                     {10039B6833}>:
    Lock on package COMMON-LISP violated when proclaiming PUSH as a function
    while in package COMMON-LISP-USER.
  See also:
    The SBCL Manual, Node "Package Locks"
    The ANSI Standard, Section 11.1.2.1.2
```

Comment: パッケージを使う。誰かがちゃんとした回答をくれるまでは次の[リンク](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~kc7k-nd/onlispjhtml/packages.html)がよくまとまっていると思うので参照してみて下さい。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

専用のパッケージを作ってみてはいかがですか。例えば、`my-stack` というパッケージを作ってみます。

```
(defpackage my-stack
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:shadow :common-lisp push pop)
  (:export stack state push pop))

(in-package :my-stack)

(defclass stack () ((state :accessor state :initform '())))

(defmethod push ((stack-obj stack) elem)
  (let ((new-stack
         (if (state stack-obj) (cons elem (state stack-obj)) (list elem))))
    (setf (state stack-obj) new-stack)))

(defmethod pop ((stack-obj stack))
  (let ((pop-stack (car (state stack-obj))))
    (progn (setf (state stack-obj) (cdr (state stack-obj)))
           pop-stack)))
```

これを、例えば `my-stack.cl` というファイルに保存して、

```
$ sbcl --load my-stack.cl
```

ロードします。そして、`my-stack` パッケージに移ります

```
* (in-package :my-stack)
#<PACKAGE "MY-STACK">

* (setq st (make-instance 'stack))

* (push st "foo")
("foo")
* (push st "bar")
("bar" "foo")
* (push st "baz")
("baz" "bar" "foo")
* (state st)
("baz" "bar" "foo")

* (pop st)
"baz"
* (state st)
("bar" "foo")
```

もしも、デフォルトパッケージにある `push` などを使いたい場合は、パッケージ名を指定して使います。

```
* (setq lst '())
* (common-lisp-user::push "foo" lst)
("foo")
```

Comment: pushはcommon-lispパッケージの外部シンボルなので、最後の例は `(common-lisp:push "foo" lst)` あるいは `(cl:push "foo" lst)` でもいけますね。::は外に見せてないものに触る手段なので裏技感が。